# Cordova build for Windows with Visual Studio 2017 error

Tags: cordova, msbuild, visual-studio-cordova

I am having issues with building a new cordova project for Windows.

I have the following versions installed:

- cordova@7.0.0, but it can also be reproduced with cordova@6.5
- Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with Tools for Apache Cordova, Windows Mobile Emulator and more.
- MS Build Tools v14 & v15 installed.

So, to reproduce:

1. `cordova create project1`
2. `cd project1`
3. `cordova platform add windows`
4. `cordova build windows`

Then the following error appears: `error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\JavaScript\Micros oft.VisualStudio.WJProject.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk`

When I add the --verbose flag to the build, I notice that the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\15.0,/v,MSBuildToolsPath` command does not return success, so it uses the Build Tools v14 instead of v15.

If I create a new project with Visual Studio 2017, it compiles & run successfully within Visual Studio, but I have the same errors on `cordova build windows` command.

I suppose that is the proper registry key were installed, it would work fine. How should I add them properly? Or what is Visual Studio doing that is not being done with the cordova or taco command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Had today the same problem and you pointed me in the right direction - thanks!

The cause for this is, that the **cordova build** command looks in the registry for the MSBuild path, but since Visual Studio 2017 Microsoft doesn't write the path in the registry anymore (more on this [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2911/vs2017-rc-installer-does-not-write-registry-entrie.html))

As workaround i created in the registry the following key (don't forget to change the path):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\15.0]
"MSBuildToolsPath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\amd64"
```

After that the cordova build worked!

Another solution would be just to install VS 2015, but in my case this was not an option, because I use the sqlite plugin in my app and the current version can only be build with VS 2017 for windows.